# Printing plugin data on QGIS map canvas

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I created a Python plugin in QGIS & when i am running my plugin it printing the data on python console. But i want that when i run my plugin it will print the data on QGIS map canvas. How can i do this?
Here is my run method which is going to print lat/long per second on Map Canvas. you just tell me how can i get lat/long on Map Canvas instead of printing it in python console.
**Remember Python version 3.6 QGIS version 3.2 & this code working fine no error**

```
def run(self):
    print('hello')
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""



    PORT_NUMBER = 5000
    SIZE = 1024

    hostName = gethostbyname('192.168.225.140')

    mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    mySocket.bind((hostName, PORT_NUMBER))

    print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))
    print ("Hi i am linux computer")

    while True:
        (data, addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print (data)





    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed


    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass
```